VSCode launch.json: Debug a spring boot project configured with gradle
I have a spring boot project that I want to debug in VSCode. I am thus tinkering with the launch.json file.
The first version of the launch.json configuration was as such:
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug Spring Boot Application",
            "request": "launch",
            "projectName": "myproj"
        },

However, this projects is configured via gradle, augmented with some flags. I am actually starting the project with this command line:
./gradlew bootRun -PspringProfile=dev --args='--spring.profiles.active=dev'.
Now, with the previous configuration, it is not starting with the right argument and I am missing some parameters, such as CORS configuration that I use only during development.
My next best modification is that configuration in the launch.json:
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug Spring Boot Application",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "gradle bootRun with Debug",
            "projectName": "myproj",
            "args": [
                "--spring.profiles.active=dev"
            ],
            "env": {
                "SPRING_PROFILE": "dev"
            }
        }

With the gradle task defined in tasks.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "gradle bootRun with Debug",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "./gradlew",
            "args": [
                "bootRun",
                "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev",
                "--debug-jvm",
                // "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "detail": "Run Spring Boot app with debug enabled"
        }
    ]
}

However, the gradle bootrun doesn't stop and I have to force manually the debug instance to run at the same time and it seems it can connect to the gradle started instance (after recompiling the whole thing, it seems). How to achieve the simple debug from the configuration in debug mode, in the cleanest way?
